# How to get data form table row ( HTML)?

Tags: php, html

My friend asked with unclearly question. So i am here and take that task for my friend.
Please for give him. Thank.

After taking the datarows form dataset as the guide on W3C( http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp), i have the below table

```
||   ID    || Name ||
||   TM001 || John || *(button)
```

i want when we press button, we can get( ID, NAME), which is in HTML form, and fill it on 2 textboxs on same page.But i am new with PHP and HTML. Therefore i have no idea how to do it. and W3c is too big for a newbie for me T_T. Could someone please give me an advice/hint. Thank alot.

Comment: `W3c is too big for a newbie for me` You should visit w3fools.com instead and you will know why it is so tough for you.

Comment: i hate to say this but  i think everyone  have the time  of a beginer.

Comment: AND PLEASE NOT BE TOXIC. It only make everyone hate u. SORRY for saying that. Thank alot for reading.

Comment: **w3fools.com** really exist , I think you misunderstood me. Have a look at that site first before reading articles on w3schools.com.

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding. It's my bad sincerely.

Comment: PLease forgive me. But w3fools.com really don't give me a help.

Comment: BUT thank anyway for ur warning. I will search for another sites. THANK a lot and hope u will forgive me, my friend.

Comment: PHP Manual is always your best hope. Start here http://us3.php.net/mysqli_query

Comment: You want to get it from `form` or `database`??

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of populating a table you might want to populate a form with data from the db?
Thread: [How to populate php/html form with MySQL data](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?45895-How-to-populate-php-html-form-with-MySQL-data)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).